# android remote bitmap is not shown

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using following method to get bitmap from url but image is not displayed. Image is a png file about 50x50px. Thank you.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
         try {
             Log.e("src",src);
             URL url = new URL(src);
             HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             connection.setDoInput(true);
             connection.connect();
             InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

             BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;


             BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input,null,options);
             Log.e("Bitmap","returned");

             //The new size we want to scale to
             final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

             //Find the correct scale value.
             int scale=1;
             while(options.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && options.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
                 scale*=2;

             //Decode with inSampleSize
             BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             o2.inSampleSize=scale;
             return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, o2);


         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
             return null;
         }


     }
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but you might want to consider refactoring the way that you are doing this.  Right now you are effectively retrieving the image from the internet twice.  This is highly wasteful of resources.  You can still accomplish your desired result, but only actually retrieving the image from the internet once.  For example, store the result into a byte array and then use that byte array to decode the bitmap twice, building your BitmapFactory.Options as needed.

Comment: He does not read the image twice. When `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;` is set this will only read the first 20 bytes of the image or so, just so that it reads the headers and writes the image size/meta data in the options instance.

Comment: Fair enough, but even assuming that only the exact bytes requested are sent (e.g. there is no buffering or compression happening along the way) it is still wasteful to make two HTTP requests for the exact same resource back-to-back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `InputStream` is "eaten away". You can use a stream only once and hence when you read the bitmap headers in order to scale the image your input stream gets 'eaten away'. You need to create a new InputStream in order to get the real bitmap.